# Disable PHP script execution on HTML file from a php include

Tags: php, html, php-include

I want to display html file content in php file script without execute any php script from html file. 
It's for security reason.

```
Files :  
|_ content 
| |_page.html 
|_page.php
```

page.php content :

```
<div>
    <span>
     <?php include('content/page.html'); ?>
    </span>
</div>
```

page.html content :

```
    <b>Titre :</b> hello world. 
<?php echo "[php execution]"; ?>
```

When I open the page.html I see:

> Titre : hello world.

when I open the page.php I see:

> Titre : hello world.[php execution]

I don't want to execute any php script on the page.html because the user can change the content. I would like to include only the html content and disable all php script execution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`include` will always exclude PHP code, but you can get round this by reading and echoing the file instead:

```
<div>
  <span>
    <?php echo file_get_contents('content/page.html'); ?>
  </span>
</div>
```